# Как сделать проверку всех соседних элементов матрицы в питоне, с учетом крайних?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, матрицы

Я новичок в питоне и мне очень хочется разобраться. Передо мной такая задача: написать функцию, которая находит все экстремумы двумерной функции, а так же возвращает листы с координатами двумерных точек: 4 листа - локальный и глобальный минимум и максимум.
В моём коде я не могу найти ни одну точку локального минимума и максимума. А в листах с глобальными минимумами и максимумами только по одному значению. Понимаю, что у меня неправильно настроена индексация в сравнении элементов, но уже который день не могу разобраться самостоятельно. Подскажите мне, пожалуйста, правильное решение...

```
x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.5)
y = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.5)

locMim = []
locMax = []
globMin = []
globMax = [] 


xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(x, y)

zgrid = xgrid * xgrid * np.sin(ygrid)

for i in range(zgrid.shape[0]):
  for j in range(zgrid.shape[1]):
    if (zgrid[i,j] == zgrid.min()):
      globMin.append(zgrid.min())

    if (zgrid[i,j] == zgrid.max()):
      globMax.append(zgrid.max())

    if (zgrid[i,j] > 0 and zgrid[i,j] < len(zgrid)-1):
      if (zgrid[i,j] - 1 > zgrid[i,j] and zgrid[i,j] + 1 > zgrid[i,j] and zgrid[i,j] != zgrid.min()):
         locMim.append(zgrid[i,j])

      if (zgrid[i,j] - 1 < zgrid[i,j] and zgrid[i,j] + 1 < zgrid[i,j] and zgrid[i,j] != zgrid.max()):
         locMax.append(zgrid[i,j])

print(locMim)
print(locMax)
print(globMin)
print(globMax)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. А почему вас смущает единственность локального максимума и минимума?
   Ну сделайте вот так, например:

> ```
> zgrid = xgrid * xgrid * np.sin(ygrid)
> zgrid1 = zgrid.reshape(1,1600)
> np.sort(zgrid1)
> ```

и получите

```
array([[-99.74949866, -98.93582466, -97.75301177, ...,  97.75301177,
         98.93582466,  99.74949866]])
```

т.е. в вашем массиве  -  на той сетке, которую вы создали  -  действительно один глобальный минимум и один глобальный максимум.

2. Про локальные минимумы-максимумы, вы что-то там перемудрили. Запишу только для максимумов -  надеюсь для минимум с настройкой справитесь сами (ну и код, конечно требует оптимизации, но я его оставляю в таком виде, что-бы вы лучше его соотнесли со своим и поняли, в чем именно вы ошиблись):

> ```
> for i in range(zgrid.shape[0]):
>     for j in range(zgrid.shape[1]):
>         if (zgrid[i,j] == zgrid.min()):
>             print(i,j,zgrid[i,j])
>         if (i > 0 and j>0 and i<zgrid.shape[0]-1 and j<zgrid.shape[1]-1):
>               if zgrid[i,j]>=max(zgrid[i-1,j-1],   
>                                            zgrid[i-1,j],
>                                            zgrid[i+1,j],
>                                            zgrid[i,j-1], 
>                                            zgrid[i,j+1]):
>                  locMax.append((zgrid[i,j],i,j))
> ```

Смотрим Содержимое locMax

```
print (locMax)

[(-0.0, 3, 20), (-0.0, 4, 20), (-0.0, 5, 20), (-0.0, 6, 20), (-0.0, 7, 20), (-0.0, 15, 20), (-0.0, 16, 20), (-0.0, 17, 20), (-0.0, 18, 20), (-0.0, 19, 20), (0.0, 20, 20), (-0.0, 28, 20), (-0.0, 29, 20), (-0.0, 30, 20), (-0.0, 31, 20), (-0.0, 32, 20), (-0.0, 3, 20), (-0.0, 4, 20), (-0.0, 5, 20), (-0.0, 6, 20), (-0.0, 7, 20), (-0.0, 15, 20), (-0.0, 16, 20), (-0.0, 17, 20), (-0.0, 18, 20), (-0.0, 19, 20), (0.0, 20, 20), (-0.0, 28, 20), (-0.0, 29, 20), (-0.0, 30, 20), (-0.0, 31, 20), (-0.0, 32, 20)]
```

Что, в общем-то вполне соответствует вашей функции, которая выглядит вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание, что выводимые индексы по координатам и значения по координатам - это разные вещи.